# what is the difference between nitro compression and vite compression in nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3, nitro

For SEO purposes I want to zip and distribute my files.

Both vite and nitro have compression options.

What's the difference between the two?

This is my nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({

    nitro: {
        compressPublicAssets: true,
        ...
    },
    vite: {
        plugins: [
            viteCompression({ algorithm: 'brotliCompress' }),
            ....
        ]
    }
```